# pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read a stream from kafka using pyspark. I am using **spark version 3.0.0-preview2** and  **spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12** 
Before this I just stat zookeeper, kafka and create a new topic:

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties 
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka/config/server.properties
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic data_wm
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import findspark
findspark.init("/usr/local/spark")
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TestApp").getOrCreate()
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "data_wm") \
  .load() 
value = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

This how I run my script:

> sudo --preserve-env=pyspark /usr/local/spark/bin/pyspark --packages
>   org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0-preview

As result for this command I have this :

```
: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-0d7b2a8d-a860-4766-a4c7-141a902d8365;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.0.0-preview in central
        found org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.0.0-preview in central
        found org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.3.1 in central
        found com.github.luben#zstd-jni;1.4.3-1 in central
        found org.lz4#lz4-java;1.6.0 in central
        found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.7.3 in central
        found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.16 in central
        found org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 in central :: resolution report :: resolve 380ms :: artifacts dl 7ms
        :: modules in use:
        com.github.luben#zstd-jni;1.4.3-1 from central in [default]
        org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.3.1 from central in [default]
        org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.0.0-preview from central in [default]
        org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.0.0-preview from central in [default]
        org.lz4#lz4-java;1.6.0 from central in [default]
        org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.16 from central in [default]
        org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 from central in [default]
        org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.7.3 from central in [default]
```

But I have always this error:

d> f = spark \ ...   .readStream \ ...   .format("kafka") \ ...

> .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \ ...
>   .option("subscribe", "data_wm") \ ...   .load()  Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "", line 5, in    File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 406, in load
>       return self._df(self._jreader.load())   File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1286, in **call**   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 102, in deco
>       **raise converted pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the
>   deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration**
>   Guide".;

I don't know the cause of this error, please help

Comment: Unrelated - Why are you using sudo to run pyspark?

Comment: And did you actually install Spark 3 preview?

Comment: even I don't use sudo I have the same problem and yes I have spark 3.0.0-preview2 installed on my laptop

Comment: Do you have the same problem not using preview version?

Comment: No even by using preview version I have the same problem

Comment: If you look at the Spark UI of the driver, do you see kafka libraries loaded?

Comment: yes of course, you can see above the result that verifies that he sees the kafka libraries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have successfully resolved this error on Spark 3.0.1 (using PySpark).

I would keep things simple and provide the desired packages through the `--packages` argument:

```bash
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1 MyPythonScript.py
```

**Mind the order of arguments otherwise it will throw an error.**

Where `MyPythonScript.py` has:

```py
KAFKA_TOPIC = "data_wm"
KAFKA_SERVER = "localhost:9092"

# creating an instance of SparkSession
spark_session = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark create RDD") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Subscribe to 1 topic
df = spark_session \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVER) \
    .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC) \
    .load()
print(df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)"))
```

Comment: You're a life-saver! It was the order of arguments causing my error! I was doing `spark-submit my-script.py --packages...` but it should have been `spark-submit --packages... my-script.py `

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation mentioned in the error, it indicates to download a different package - `spark-sql-kafka`, **not** `spark-streaming-kafka`. You can see in your `resolving dependencies` log section, you do not have that.

You can also add packages via findspark rather than at the CLI

Answer (score 0):

For Spark 3.3.0, [this](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y0000970WIHSA2/spark-330-connect-kafka-problem) helped me (bringing relevant jars to project)