# Structured Streaming + Kafka: RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number + Failed to find data source: kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

i am trying to use kafka as streamer and use spark to process data

**config:**

- python3.9
- Kubuntu 21.10
- echo $JAVA_HOME : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
- echo $SPARK_HOME: /opt/spark
- spark version: 3.2.0
- pyspark version: pyspark-3.2.1-py2.py3
- downloaded kafka version: kafka_2.13-3.1.0.tgz
  kafka status:
- :~$ sudo systemctl status kafka
  kafka.service - Apache Kafka Server
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kafka.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-01-29 19:02:18 +0330; 4s ago
  Docs: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html
  Main PID: 5271 (java)
  Tasks: 74 (limit: 19017)
  Memory: 348.7M
  CPU: 5.188s

my python program:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import time
import os
import findspark as fs
fs.init()


spark_version = '3.2.0'
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_3.1.0:{}'.format(spark_version)
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64'

# os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--master local[2] pyspark-shell"

kafka_topic_name = "bdCovid19"

kafka_bootstrap_servers = 'localhost:9092'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Welcome to DataMaking !!!")
    print("Stream Data Processing Application Started ...")
    print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka and Message Format as JSON") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    # Construct a streaming DataFrame that reads from test-topic
    orders_df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
        .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
        .load()
```

running on pycharm

**Error:**

raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

in this line:  `spark = SparkSession \`

**IF** i remove `os.environ` lines from the code that error disaper but a got this :

raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException:  Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".

in this line:  `orders_df = spark \`

**I have read these:**

1. [Pyspark: Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841509/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-po)
2. [Creating sparkContext on Google Colab gives: `RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548399/creating-sparkcontext-on-google-colab-gives-runtimeerror-java-gateway-process)
3. [Spark + Python - Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825911/spark-python-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-port)
4. [Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
   #743](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/743)
5. [Pyspark: Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number](https://intellipaat.com/community/6909/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-port-number)
6. [Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (Kafka broker version 0.10.0 or higher)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)
7. [pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230124/pyspark-sql-utils-analysisexception-failed-to-find-data-source-kafka)

none of them worked for me! any suggestions?

Comment: 1) The `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` should be assigned before findspark and before spark are imported. 2) You're using the wrong version of the kafka package, should match your Spark version 3) you can add `--packages` line when you actually run spark-submit, or modify the environment variables *in Pycharm* rather than code to set PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS

Comment: could you tell me what version# of kafka should i use?